# KSQL Datagen - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MonitoringProducerInterceptor

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am exploring confluent Kafka and following this quickstart guide from [confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/cos-quickstart.html#cos-quickstart). I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor` whenever I try to create some sample data for the Kafka topics using the following command:

```
bin/ksql-datagen quickstart=pageviews format=delimited topic=pageviews maxInterval=100 \ propertiesFile=etc/ksql/datagen.properties
```

Here's the stack trace

```
Outputting 1000000 to pageviews
[2018-08-01 11:37:06,323] INFO AvroDataConfig values: 
    schemas.cache.config = 1
    enhanced.avro.schema.support = false
    connect.meta.data = true
 (io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroDataConfig:179)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:460)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:320)
    at io.confluent.ksql.datagen.DataGenProducer.populateTopic(DataGenProducer.java:76)
    at io.confluent.ksql.datagen.DataGen.main(DataGen.java:100)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor ClassNotFoundException exception occurred
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:357)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:332)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:319)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:381)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadClass(Utils.java:333)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:322)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstances(AbstractConfig.java:355)
    ... 6 more
```

I have followed every step given in the quickstart guide, what is that I am doing wrong?

I even have restated the confluent, but still getting the same error as opposed to what mentioned in this [google group answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/confluent-platform/x2ZE5_S1_t4/dyytaomYBAAJ)

Comment: What version of Confluent Platform are you using?

Comment: I am using Confluent 5.0.0. I think the issue is due to control-center not getting started up. But I am not able to understand why it is not starting after running bin/confluent start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into same issue and found it only work with Confluent Enterprise in /etc/ksql/datagen.properties:

```
# This properties file should ONLY be used when you run KSQL with Confluent Enterprise Platform.
interceptor.classes=io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor
```

It works after removing propertiesFile:

```
/bin/ksql-datagen quickstart=pageviews format=delimited topic=pageviews maxInterval=100
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks it works for me. But they should have mentioned somewhere in the documents that these commands are for enterprise edition, not open source.

Answer (score 0):

> Placing `monitoring-interceptors.jar` in KSQL(or which ever confluent service failing due to this error) **classpath**(*$CONFLUENT_HOME/share/java/ksql/*)
>    should solve the issue

possible location of jar apart from confluent maven repo

*$CONFLUENT_HOME/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-*.jar*